# Log4j File created but empty

Tags: java, logging, exe4j

**Tried other question answers but couldn't overcome the problem**

I have xml file for configure the log4j. Two log files are created but files are empty. I cannot write to a file.

This is my xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">


<log4j:configuration
 xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

 <appender name="ErrorAPPENDER"
  class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="D://Error.log" />
  <param name="Append" value="true" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern"
    value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm:ss},%m%n" />
  </layout>
 </appender>

 <appender name="EventAPPENDER"
  class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="D://Event.log" />
  <param name="Append" value="true" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern"
    value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm:ss},%m%n" />
  </layout>
 </appender>
 
 <appender name="ConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
  </layout>
 </appender>

 <logger name="Event" additivity="false">
  <level value="debug" />
  <appender-ref ref="EventAPPENDER" />
 </logger>

 <logger name="Error" additivity="false">
  <level value="debug" />
  <appender-ref ref="ErrorAPPENDER" />
 </logger>



 <root>
  <priority value="debug" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
 </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

And this is the initialize class

```
package com.mobios.common;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class Log4JUtil {

    public static final Logger logger=   Logger.getLogger(Log4JUtil.class);

}
```

And this is how i logging

```
Log4JUtil.logger.getLogger("ErrorAPPENDER").error("sdsffd");
```

**But nothing writes on the log file. I cannot see any error and i tried the solutions mentioned in other questions.**

Answer (score 1):

A logger is always identified by a unique name across all the loggers initialized until now

Logging.getLogger(Log4jUtil.class) creates a logger with name "com.mobios.common.Log4jUtil" (Log4jUtil.class.getName()) or returns an already created logger with that name
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html#getLogger(java.lang.Class)

In your log4j.xml file, you have not created any logger with the name "com.mobios.common.Log4jUtil". You created loggers with names "Event", "Error"

You can add a section in your log4j.xml file with "com.mobios.common.Log4jUtil" and add the "Event" and "Error" handlers to it so that it logs to the corresponding files

```
<logger name="com.mobios.common.Log4jUtil" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="EventAPPENDER" />
    <appender-ref ref="ErrorAPPENDER" />
</logger>
```

While logging, you don't need to log the messages with getLogger() call again.
In your Log4jUtil.class, you can simply do,

```
logger.error("sdsffd")
```

In other classes, if you want to use the logger from Log4jUtil.class, you can do
`Logger.getLogger(Log4JUtil.class)` and this returns an already instantiated logger with the handlers attached

```
package com.mobios.common;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class AnotherClass {

    public static final Logger logger=   Logger.getLogger(Log4JUtil.class);

}
```

Comment: As you said i have added the logger part to the xml. But still not working. But your solution is seem ok. But not work for me. I have figure out this. If i add <appender-ref ref="ErrorAPPENDER" /> to the root tag it going to write everything from application stat to that error file. But it is not what i need. I need to write only errors in error file and info in event file. #pvpks